# setAsync returns success status but not inserting data in MAC installed outlook

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

here I am implementing an email tracking system using image insertion , and i used 'Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync' office API , everywhere it is working but not in installed MAC outlook though it returns 'success' in asyncResult.status.Please help me out.

Comment: Can you try prependAsync? Looks like setAsync does not work as expected on outlook for MAC.

Comment: Can you please share the build number you are using?

Comment: @DeepakSharma - prependAsync not working as well.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility - i am using : macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)  and Outlook - 15.36

Answer (score 1):

Also, as a reference you can try the below mentioned code snippet:

```
var htmlData =  '<img src=\"https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg\">';
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
 htmlData, 
 {coercionType: "html"}, 
 function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
      console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Successfully set body text");
    }
 }
);
```

Comment: I have used like that only but could not understand why it not getting inserted

Answer (score -1):

```
/* ReadWriteItem or ReadWriteMailbox */
/* Set body content */
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
  '<img src=\"https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg\">', 
   {coercionType: "html"}, 
   function (asyncResult) {
     if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
       console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
     } else {
       console.log("Successfully set body text");
     }
   });
```

I used above  code and it worked in 15.40